# Realm databases in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I copy data from Realm database to list

in past it like this:

> Realm e.g.:r=Realm.getInstance(getapplictioncontext);
>
> r.beginTransaction;
>
> list x=r.allobjects(x.class);

But now I don't know how can any body help and thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Here is the small snippet about realm. I had used it in my application. 
[see method loadBlockedContacts()](https://github.com/abhishekborikar/Perfect_Call_Manager/blob/master/app/src/main/java/abhishek/redvelvet/com/perfect_call_manager/call_setting/blocked_call/ShowBlockedContactsActivity.java)

The following first line

```
RealmResults<BlockedContactsData> result = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(BlockedContactsData.class);
```

will extract data from realm database. Then after map it as per your requirement.